# What site(s) to select for fruit trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, planting

I plan to plant a few fruit trees in my backyard in San Mateo, CA. I'm thinking citrus and maybe cherries or plums. I have the following "options" to plant them, none of which get 8+ hours of sunlight a day:

option 1: Early morning sun, till about 2:30 PM.

option 2: late-morning to early evening sun, from about 11AM to 5:30PM

option 3: noon-evening sun, from about noon to 6:30PM

these times are in July, so there will be seasonal variations of course. The lack of sunlight is a function of the yard's orientation, and fences and other trees casting shadows.

If i had to order these sites based on desirability, how would I do it? I'm a complete newbie when it comes to gardening.

Comment: I found the agriculture department of the state university had several very informative free booklets. Today I expect there is a charge.